# Visibility of user tags

Tags: discussion

If a user is tagged with a @ symbol is mentioned  in a comment that they did not start or otherwise were involved in, would they get a notification?

There have been times in which feedback from specific users would have been helpful in some of my questions, based on them also working in Infosec per their user profile. An example is this

[Communicating with prospective vendor about official documents](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/106837/communicating-with-prospective-vendor-about-official-documents)

Comment: Here's a Meta post giving a run-down of how user tags work: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 5):

> If a user is tagged with a @ symbol is mentioned in a comment that they did not start or otherwise were involved in, would they get a notification?

As far as I know, these are the situations in which you will receive a notification:

- If you comment under someone's post (Q or A) they will be notified regardless you used the @ tagging.
- If some user commented under some post, you can then proceed to @ tag them and they will be notified.

Do note that if a user has not joined the comment thread, or it's not their post they will *not* be notified (again, as far as I know/recall).

This is similar to chat; you can @ tag someone in chat only if they have joined chat recently, otherwise the tagging will be ineffective (and you won't get an auto-complete suggestion).

In a few words, I think that if you don't get the auto-complete suggestion the user won't be notified, unless it's their own post.

*Edit:* Consider checking this link David shared from MSE that explains tagging on detail: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/332286)

Comment: I think the one exception is that if you and the OP are the only people who have commented on a post, you will be notified regardless of whether you have been tagged. It's been a while since I've had this happen, so I don't know if those mechanics are exactly right. It might happen if you and someone other than the OP are the only commenters as well, but not sure. I know that the user will be notified if it doesn't let you @ someone who has already commented.

Comment: OP was talking specifically about using the @ to tag, but yes like you say if I'm not mistaken (and this comment may prove it) I can skip the @you at all here and will still notify you, as it's a direct reply to the last comment (yours)...

Comment: Yup, you are correct! :) I specifically mentioned it because if I try to @ you, it won't let me because you are notified by default. I think the opposite may be true as well. Also, as I learned from the [Meta post about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), you can @ editors, even though their name doesn't auto-fill!

Comment: yup, I also got notified :D